# Safari does not add a break when hitting enter

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I want a user to be able to type in a content editable div, hit enter (or come to the end of the line) and have their text collected into a variable and have their cursor put on a new line, standard for any text editor.  I have this event listner that checks for those conditions:

```
writerId.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){


  if(event.key === "Enter" || document.getElementById("writer").offsetWidth >= "570") {

    if(initialState === true) {

      writtingContent = writerId.innerHTML;
      blurId.innerHTML = writtingContent ;
      writerId.innerHTML = "";
      initialState = false;
    } else {
        writtingContent = writtingContent + writerId.innerHTML;
        blurId.innerHTML = writtingContent ;
        writerId.innerHTML = "";
    }

 }

});
```

The new line works in Chrome, FireFox but not Safari.
Initially I added this as a workaround for Safari:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
    writtingContent = writtingContent + "</br>";
    console.log(navigator.userAgent);
  }
```

But it broke things in other browsers (specifically Opera) and I've read that `navigator.userAgent` is not the best way to go about browser specific issues anyway.

I've seen some workarounds with feature detection but I'm not sure if that's necessary; I'd love if there was an easier way; something, perhaps, I've overlooked.